# InnerHTML not read below html unicode in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, angular

my.ts file

```
this.posts = [{"title":"title 1","body":"It\\u2019s a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum.\\n"},{"title":"title 2","body":"It is a long \\u2012 established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its \\u2045 layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum\\n"}]
```

**Note that i am getting given json array from the server**

Html file

```
<div [innerHTML]="post.body"></div>
```

Output
[image]

i need this output
[image]

thanks in advances

Comment: The source should be just `\u2012` not two backslashes.

Comment: The backslash is escaped in the data you're receiving, so what's happening is correct. You need to fix the data source to produce it correctly (with just one backslash, not two): `..."body":"It\u2019s...`

Comment: thanks for reply. if you know any solution to fix the data source to produce it correctly then please suggest. I have tried regex to do so `str.replace(/\\/g, '\')` .But it's not working because i can't use \ alone in string.